# Eloquent relationship between Hospital and Unit models in Laravel is not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to establish a one-to-many relationship between Hospital and Unit models in Laravel. A hospital can have many units, while a unit belongs to one hospital. However, the association doesn't seem to work as expected.

Here is my `Hospital` model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Hospital extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function units()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Unit::class);
    }
}
```

And here is my `Unit` model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Unit extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function hospital()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Hospital::class);
    }

    public function benefits()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Benefit::class, 'benefit_unit');
    }
}
```

Here is the code that I use to associate a hospital with a unit:

```
$unit = Unit::create($unitData);
$unit->hospital()->associate($hospital)->save();
```

manual code works for me:

```
$hospitalUnitData = [
                'hospital_id' => $hospital->id,
                'unit_id' => $unit->id,
            ];
            DB::table('hospital_unit')->insert($hospitalUnitData);
```

schemas:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateHospitalsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('hospitals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('hospitals');
    }
}

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUnitsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('units', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->uuid('hospital_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('hospital_id')->references('id')->on('hospitals');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('units');
    }
}

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateHospitalUnitTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('hospital_unit', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->uuid('hospital_id');
            $table->uuid('unit_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('hospital_id')->references('id')->on('hospitals')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('unit_id')->references('id')->on('units')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('hospital_unit');
    }
}
```

Comment: One to many does not need a pivot table, the only case is many to many, so you need to explain what you are expecting, else we are just guessing... what you have done is a correct one to many (on the code, not the migration), but you want a many to many, you want the same unit to work with more than 1 hospital, but that hospital can only have 1 unit (at least of that type). So your solution is not one to many, but many to many... Still please do explain what you expect, that is very important and missing here...

Comment: For example, if you expect to have 1 unit for 1 hospital, but a hospital can have more than 1 units, then `units` table should have `hospital_id`, no pivot. If you expect to have 1 unit for more than 1 hospital (because the unit is the same, so you don't duplicate), then you need a pivot table

Comment: @matiaslauriti no no, units are like departments. I have many hospitals. Every single hospital has many units. But single unit is dedicated only to one hospital. So it's one to many relation, I believe. So as I understand I don't need pivot table for one-to-many relation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot table is only needed for many-to-many relationship.

For one-to-many relationship, all you need is a refernce ID on the model that belongs to a certain, model,

Simply think of them like this, you have hospital and unit model unit,

how do you get all units of hospital A? You simply query the Unit table with `hostpal_id` of hospital A (**HasMany**)

how do you determine what is the hospital of a unit? you get the hospital based on `hostpal_id` stored on that unit column (**BelongsTo**)

you see, you dont need an intermediate (pivot) table to connect hospital and unit.

when you call this `$unit->hospital()->associate($hospital)->save();` its not updating your `hospital_unit` table because it updates the relationship of your `Hospital` and `Unit` relationship which is one-to-many,

which mean its just updating/adding the **Hospital** id to the `hospital_id` from the Unit table and not creating pivot entry in `hospital_unit` table as the relationship is not many-to-many